# random behavior when scrolling a horizontal collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal collection view that got 5 cells with a labbel and a view with a background set. in the last item I want the background to be hidden. so I changed it like this.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = cell as! CartStepMenuCell
    let index = indexPath.item
    if index == 4{
        cell.seperator.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

The thing is when scrolling back and forth, the first cell's bakckground get hidden and last one is not.

Comment: Just add `else` part in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views in a collectionView are reused, so everything you do to a view must also be undone.  My rule is any code that touches a reuseable view cannot have an `if` without an `else`.  In this case you can remove the `if` entirely:

```
    cell.seperator.isHidden = (index == 4)
```

This way it is correctly set and unset when reused.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
let cell = cell as! CartStepMenuCell 
cell.seperator.isHidden = indexPath.item == arr.count - 1
```

collectionView cells are dequeued , so you have to give else option or as above , also don't put static counts put your array count in case you append or remove from the array the last item is the 1 intact